# How do I calculate the rest/modulo of two numbers without the "%" operator?

Tags: java, math, methods, bit-manipulation, modulo

For example with the following input:

```
int num = -100
int divisor = 10
=>  -100 mod 10 = 0   (Edge-case: negative numbers as input)
```

---

```
int num = 300
int divisor = -7
=>300 mod 7 = 6
```

---

I used this method before but with negative numbers, it´s not working:

```
int method(int i, int div){
    return (num - divisor * (num / divisor));
}
```

Expected result :

```
-1234, 512 ==> <302>
```

Actual result :

```
-1234, 512 ==> <210>
```

Comment: @Sweeper I added for what input it doesn't work

Comment: Actually, `Math.floorMod` seems to do what you want. Maybe you can have a look at the source code of that.

Comment: How you are expecting 302. Can you explain pls. Your expected result 302 is wrong. 210 is the correct answer.

Comment: @ahhwhattdexxterr :  Have tried your code, with both negative and positive no, it is giving same outcome. -210 and 210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your method.

```
static int method(int num, int div){
   return num - div * (num / div);
}
```

It works fine as it returns a remainder regardless of the signs used just like 
`%`.  But if you want more of a `positive mod` answer you need to do the following:

```
static int method(int num, int div){
   int mod = num - div * (num / div);
   return (mod < 0) ? mod + div : mod;
}
```

From the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/jvms14.pdf) for **irem**.

> Both value1 and value2 must be of type int. The values are popped
>   from the operand stack. The int result is value1 - (value1 / value2)
>   * value2. The result is pushed onto the operand stack.

Answer (score 0):

The following test proves that your initial implementation provides the same results as original `%` operator:

```
static int mod(int n, int m) {
    return n - m * (n / m);
}
// test
int[][] data = {
    {100, 10}, {-100, 10}, {100, -10}, {-100, -10},
    {   5, 3}, {-  5,  3}, {  5, - 3}, {-  5, - 3}
};

Arrays.stream(data)
      .forEach(d -> System.out.printf("%s: %d %% %d = %d mod=%d%n",
               d[0]%d[1] == mod(d[0], d[1]) ? "OK" : "BAD", 
               d[0], d[1], d[0]%d[1], mod(d[0], d[1])));
```

Output:

```
OK: 100 % 10 = 0 mod=0
OK: -100 % 10 = 0 mod=0
OK: 100 % -10 = 0 mod=0
OK: -100 % -10 = 0 mod=0
OK: 5 % 3 = 2 mod=2
OK: -5 % 3 = -2 mod=-2
OK: 5 % -3 = 2 mod=2
OK: -5 % -3 = -2 mod=-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine with modulo and without module.

They both give same results for negative and positive numbers as well.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the Dividend : ");
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nEnter the Divisor : ");
        int div = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Without modulo :Dividend: " + i + " , Divisor: " + div + ", Remainder: "  +(i - div * (i / div)));
        System.out.println("With modulo    :Dividend: " + i + " , Divisor: " + div + ", Remainder: "  +(i % div));
        System.out.println("Using abstract :Dividend: " + i + " , Divisor: " + div + ", Remainder: "  +Math.abs(i - div * (i / div)));

    }
}
```

Output :

```
Enter the Dividend :                                                                                                                                        
300                                                                                                                                                       
Enter the Divisor :                                                                                                                                         
-7                                                                                                                                                          
Without modulo :Dividend: 300 , Divisor: -7, Remainder: 6                                                                                                   
With module    :Dividend: 300 , Divisor: -7, Remainder: 6
Using abstract :Dividend: 300,  Divisor: -7, Remainder: 6

Enter the Dividend :                                                                                                                                          
-1234                                                                                                                                                         

Enter the Divisor :                                                                                                                                           
512                                                                                                                                                           
Without modulo :Dividend: -1234 , Divisor: 512, Remainder: -210                                                                                               
With module    :Dividend: -1234 , Divisor: 512, Remainder: -210
Using abstract :Dividend: -1234 , Divisor: 512, Remainder: 210
```